# Python 3.4.1 make test Fails: ERROR: test_connect_starttls (test.test_smtpnet.SmtpTest)

Tags: python, ssl

I just downloaded python 3.4.1 on my centos 6.4 virtual machine and was following the instructions in the readme.  first I did ./configure, then make, then make test.

When I ran make test it had an error, I have no idea why, I just followed the instructions exactly as they were given.  here is the output:

```
test test_smtpnet failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/test/test_smtpnet.py", line 30, in test_connect_starttls
    server = smtplib.SMTP(self.testServer, self.remotePort)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/socket.py", line 495, in create_connection
    sock = socket(af, socktype, proto)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/socket.py", line 123, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
368 tests OK.
1 test failed:
    test_smtpnet
7 tests altered the execution environment:
    test_calendar test_float test_locale test_site test_strptime
    test_types test_warnings
12 tests skipped:
    test_curses test_devpoll test_gdb test_kqueue test_msilib
    test_ossaudiodev test_startfile test_tk test_ttk_guionly
    test_winreg test_winsound test_zipfile64
Re-running failed tests in verbose mode
Re-running test 'test_smtpnet' in verbose mode
test_connect_starttls (test.test_smtpnet.SmtpTest) ... ERROR
test_connect (test.test_smtpnet.SmtpSSLTest) ... ok
test_connect_default_port (test.test_smtpnet.SmtpSSLTest) ... ok
test_connect_using_sslcontext (test.test_smtpnet.SmtpSSLTest) ... ok
test_connect_using_sslcontext_verified (test.test_smtpnet.SmtpSSLTest) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: test_connect_starttls (test.test_smtpnet.SmtpTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/test/test_smtpnet.py", line 30, in test_connect_starttls
    server = smtplib.SMTP(self.testServer, self.remotePort)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/socket.py", line 495, in create_connection
    sock = socket(af, socktype, proto)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.1/Lib/socket.py", line 123, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 42.864s

FAILED (errors=1)
test test_smtpnet failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

so it seems like the _socket module tried using an "address family" (whatever the heck that is) that is not supported by the protocol.  Can this exception be more vague please?

Does anybody know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the test case does require IPv6 to be enabled. Therefore it will fail on a system without IPv6 support enabled. Check the output of `ip a s` to see if the VM has an IPv6 address set, e.g usually starting with `fe80::`. Address family can be AF_INET for IPv4 or AF_INET6 for IPv6. 
Actually,that is a test case bug.